# Operator in funtional space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X = \{f :[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}/ f \hspace{1.0mm} is \hspace{1.0mm} continous\}$ and $T(f)_{(x)} = \int_{0}^{x}{f_{(s)}ds} $.

1. Prove that $\hspace{3.0mm}T^n(f)_{(x)} = \int_{0}^{x}{K_{n}(x,s)f(s)ds}\hspace{3.0mm}$ where $K_{n}$ is continous in $[0,1]$x$[0,1]$
2. Find $\|T\|$ and find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{T^n}$
3. Solve the ecuation $(I-T)f = g$

Note: the norm we consider is the norm of uniform convergence in $X$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

1. By induction, we can prove that
   $$\left( {{T^{\left( n \right)}}f} \right)\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{{\left( {n - 1} \right)!}}\int_0^x {{{\left( {x - s} \right)}^{n - 1}}u\left( s \right)ds} ,\,\forall n \geqslant 2,\,x \in \left[ {0,1} \right].$$
2. We have
   $$\left\| {Tf} \right\| = \mathop {\sup }\limits_{x \in \left[ {0,1} \right]} \left| {\int_0^x {f\left( s \right)ds} } \right| \leqslant \left\| f \right\|,$$
   with $f \equiv 1$ we have $\left\| T \right\| = 1$.
3. You can use Fredholm alternative.